# Content Slideshow Plugin

Tags: plugins, gallery, slideshow

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what wordpress plugin I can use to create a similar type of slideshow plugin as the ones that are used on Refinery29? Here is a link to an example...

http://www.refinery29.com/rooftop-bars-nyc/slideshow#slide-1

What I like about this particular slideshow/gallery is that the images don't auto-resize to fit into a fixed gallery box, the slides are numbered, there is a full-screen option.

I also like that each slide is a new URL - better click-through rate I would assume.

This is another example that I like as well...

http://www.wellandgoodnyc.com/2013/06/03/7-stunning-summer-yoga-escapes/

If anyone can provide any suggestions (free or premium plugins), I would be forever grateful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jquery carousel lite is easy to implement and adapt to your needs;

[http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

for more heavyweight stuff you could use jquery carousel

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/